# Absolute continuity with respect to Lebesgue measure

Tags: linear-algebra, lebesgue-measure

What does it mean for a joint distribution (x,y) to have absolute continuity with respect to a Lebesgue measure ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_measures

Comment: It simply means $(x,y)$ has a joint density $f_{x,y}$.

Comment: are u sure about that , what about the measure and absolute continuity